# Add "you say" when asking a rhetorical question

Tags: phrases

Is it possible to add "you say" at the end of a rhetorical question?
Let me give you an example:
Someone says that their new job involves dancing - and then you respond by asking "Dancing, you say?"
-- Would that work? Is this an idiomatic phrase? What would be the connotation?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. It is like saying: Did you say dancing? In a nice way.